# Rails4 collection_select with data options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dropdownbox, collection-select

i want to reproduce the following select structure using FormHelper

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." name="select2" class="required select">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="opt2">India</option>
            <option value="opt2">United States of America</option>
          </select>
```

### What i have tried?

```
    <%= f.collection_select(:country_id, @countries, :id, :name, { :prompt => true }, 
{ :class => 'select', :selected => params[:country_id], :date => {:placeholder => 'Choose a Country...' }}) %>
```

But the Placeholder tag does not get picked up and it shows `Please Select`

Comment: remove `{ :prompt => true }`? Options should be in one scope i guess.

Answer (score 1):

This:

`= collection_select("user", "country_id", @countries, :id, :name, {:prompt => true}, { :class => 'select', :selected => 1, "data-placeholder" => 'Choose a Country...' })`

Returns this html (i add `user` to test):

```
<select class="select" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="user_country_id" name="user[country_id]" selected="selected"><option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">Russia</option>
<option value="2">USA</option></select>
```

So this what you expected i guess, but for me it doesn't show placeholder. To show it, just change `prompt` to you placeholder title:

```
f.collection_select(:country_id, @countries, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Choose a Country...'}, { :class => 'select', :selected => params[:country_id])
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: this works. but i wanna pass it off as a data-placeholder for my plugin to capture and style it

Comment: What if `:prompt => 'Choose a Country...'` and `"data-placeholder" => 'Choose a Country...' }`?

Comment: no its not getting picked up. looks like the theme needs data-placeholder but am not able to set i the way you suggested or other answers

Answer (score 1):

From rails documentation

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

As per the syntax `:selected` parameter should go inside `options` instead of `html_options`

All you need to do is remove `:selected` parameter from `html_options` and include it inside `options`

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:country_id, @countries, :id, :name, { :prompt => true, :selected => params[:country_id] }, { :class => 'select', :date => {:placeholder => 'Choose a Country...' }}) %>
```

Comment: then placing the selected as you mention. after a failed validation it doesnt retain the value. in my case it does :(

Comment: My guess is you need to change params[:country_id] to something that returns a saved value from db like @user.country_id

Comment: no it cut and paste the same thing to back where i had put. pretty wierd.